# Fetching image from url and storing it locally then use these image in listiew

Tags: android

I want to save the images from url on my device and then use the images stored on the device to populate the listview and also wanted to know where to store images on device either on phone memory or in cache

Comment: Questions like these are too broad to answer here.

Comment: And we're supposed to write the full code now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new ImageDownloader().execute(downloadUrl);


private class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return downloadBitmap(param[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPreExecute Called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result));
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();

    }

    private String downloadBitmap(String url) {
        // initilize the default HTTP client object
        final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //forming a HttoGet request 
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            //check 200 OK for success
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + 
                        " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;

            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    // getting contents from the stream 
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    return SaveBitmapToDir(bitmap);
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                    " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
        } 

        return null;
    }

    private String SaveBitmapToDir(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        File file = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss");
            String dateTime = s.format(new Date());
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            file = new File(path, "MyApp_"+dateTime+".jpg");
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```